# How can I find numbers with repeating digits in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, digits

Given a range of numbers between a and b, I need to find all numbers that have repeating digits. They don't have to be consecutive repeating digits- for example 121 would count as one of these numbers.
I already coded the input of the vector list itself - I just don't know how to analyze the digits of each individual item in that vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //variables
    int a, b, i = 0; // a & b inputs, i for iterating

    //entering number range
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;


    //making a vector to contain numbers between a and b
    vector<int> listofnums((b-a)+1); 
    int initialvalue = a;
    while (i <= (b-a)) {  
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 
        initialvalue++; 
        i++;
    }

    //printing the completed vector
    for ( const auto &item : listofnums ){
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    //analyzing the digits of each item in the vector
    //code for finding repeating digits here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a counting table and modulo div loop, similar to what you would do when converting bases.

Comment: Convert the numbers to strings.  Easier to access the digits (as an array of characters).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the lowest (least significant) digit of a decimal number by taking the remainder after dividing it by 10; in `C++` this is readily accomplished using the modulo operator (`%`). Thus, given a *integer* variable, `a`, with a value of `123`, the statement `int b = a % 10;` will assign `3` to `b`.

Now, by running a loop in which we sequentially divide the 'test' number by 10 (until it reaches zero), we can get the values for each digit. If we keep an array of `bool` values, setting each one to `true` when we find a given digit, we can quickly detect a repeated digit.

Thus, this function will do the job:

```cpp
bool HasRepeatDigit(int x)
{
    bool hasDigit[10] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    while (x > 0) {
        int digit = x % 10;
        if (hasDigit[digit]) return true; // We already have this digit!
        hasDigit[digit] = true; // Flag the digit we just found
        x /= 10; // Divide by 10, to move onto the next digit
    }
    return false; // If we get here, there is no repeat digit!
}
```

You can then call this function on each of your 'test' numbers in a second loop, adding those numbers that have repeated digits to a new vector:

```cpp
vector<int> withRepeats;
for (auto i : listofnums) { // Tests "i" for every element in listofnums
    if (HasRepeatDigit(i)) withRepeats.push_back(i); // Append this to the new vector
}
```

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

As an aside, you can reduce the code that fills your `listofnums` vector using the [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function (defined in the `<numeric>` header):

```cpp
#include <numeric>
//...
std::iota(begin(listofnums), end(listofnums), a);
```

Comment: Would I have to put that within another loop to implement it for each value of my vector? (I'm sorry if these are simple questions - this is my second week of c++ class and the jump between the last assignment and this one is huge)

Comment: @SaraMillan You can test the numbers after you've added them to your first vector, as shown, or you *could* do it all in one loop - by testing each number before you add it to the 'answer' vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool duplicated_digits( int value )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    std::bitset<Base> b;

    bool is_duplicate = false;

    do
    {
        int digit = value % Base;

        if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;

        b.flip( digit );
        is_duplicate = not b.test( digit );
    } while ( not is_duplicate && ( value /= Base ) != 0 );

    return is_duplicate;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0; 

    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    std::tie( a, b ) = std::minmax( { a, b } );

    std::vector<int> v; 

    int current_value = a;
    do
    {
        if ( duplicated_digits( current_value ) ) v.push_back( current_value );
    } while ( current_value++ != b );

    if ( not v.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "There are the following numbers with duplicated digits "
                     "in the range [ "
                  << a << ", " << b << " ]\n";                   
        for ( const auto &item : v )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There are no numbers with duplicated digits in the range [ "
                  << a << ", " << b << " ]\n";                   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look for example the following way

```
Enter the first number: 50
Enter the second number: -50
There are the following numbers with duplicated digits in the range [ -50, 50 ]
-44 -33 -22 -11 11 22 33 44
```

Or another example of possible program output

```
Enter the first number: -100
Enter the second number: -130
There are the following numbers with duplicated digits in the range [ -130, -100 ]
-122 -121 -119 -118 -117 -116 -115 -114 -113 -112 -111 -110 -101 -100
```

Answer (score 0):

There are one million solutions. Everybody can do, what he wants

The standard approach in C++ for these types of problem is to use a `std::map` as a counter. A std::map has an index operator. The index operator returns a reference to a value, if the key isexisting. If the key is not existing, it will create a new entry and then return a reference to the default initialized value.

We then increment the reference.

Before that, we convert the integer to a string and then work on the chararcters(digits). Counting is then as easy as:

```
for (const char& digit : numberAsString) counter[digit]++;
```

We put all the operations into a function and can then use this in C++ algorithms.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool check(const int& i) {
    // Convert int to string
    std::string numberAsString{ std::to_string(i) };

    // We will use a map as counter
    std::map<char, size_t> counter{};

    // Count the digits
    for (const char& digit : numberAsString) counter[digit]++;

    // Search for a digit count > 1
    bool result{};
    for (const auto& [digit, count] : counter)  if (count > 1) { result = true; break; };

    return result;
}


using namespace std;

int main() {
    //variables
    int a, b, i = 0; // a & b inputs, i for iterating

    //entering number range
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;


    //making a vector to contain numbers between a and b
    vector<int> listofnums((b - a) + 1);
    int initialvalue = a;
    while (i <= (b - a)) {
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;
        initialvalue++;
        i++;
    }

    //printing the completed vector
    for (const auto& item : listofnums) {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    cout << '\n';

    //analyzing the digits of each item in the vector
    //code for finding repeating digits here

    // Example 1
    // print out all values in the vector having this property
    cout << "\n\n Result:\n";
    copy_if(listofnums.begin(), listofnums.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\n"), check);

    // Example 2
    // copy all thos values to a new vector
    vector<int> result;
    copy_if(listofnums.begin(), listofnums.end(), back_inserter(result), check);

    return 0;
}
```